# Custom shaped standalone windows app using Electron

Tags: linux, windows, macos, window, electron

I was wondering if it will be possible to launch a custom shaped independent window/element from an [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) app. Something like the chat heads that we have for Facebook app in android.

Where should I start? If not in electron would it be possible with any other html framework for that matter.

[image: An example seen in android. However am looking at having this in mac/windows/linux]

An example seen in android. However am looking at having this in mac/windows/linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are `frameless-windows` in Electron. When you construct your BrowserWindow object pass `transparent: true` as an option.

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({ transparent: true});
```

If you don't want a frame around your window you might want to pass `frame: false` as an option as well.

```
var win = new BrowserWindow({ transparent: true, frame: false});
```

NOTE: Unfortunately, you can't click through the frame-window as of yet, as they are still working on it. Read more about that [here](https://github.com/atom/electron/issues/1335).

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial with a similar frameless window concept on Medium by Kristian Poslek: https://medium.com/developers-writing/building-a-desktop-application-with-electron-204203eeb658#.n82fds6ra. It's a nice article and he provides a repo at https://github.com/bojzi/sound-machine-electron-guide.git.

The custom app he demos is rectangular, with no "window chrome" or menu except for on the Mac - the default app menu appears.